# Error "The type or namespace name 'ProfileCommon' could not be found"

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'm trying to set up a YAF forum 1.9.4 and am having a problem with the profile section in the config:

```
<profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="YafProfileProvider"
         inherits="YAF.Classes.Utils.YafUserProfile">
<providers>
<clear/>
<add connectionStringName="ConfettiSQL" name="YafProfileProvider" 
     type="YAF.Providers.Profile.YafProfileProvider"/>
</providers>
</profile>
```

When I tested this locally everything worked fine but on on my web server I get the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'ProfileCommon' could not be found
```

I have uploaded all files and I can see a file called "YAF.Providers.dll" in my bin folder.

Anyone know how to fix this error please?

Comment: <profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="YafProfileProvider" inherits="YAF.Classes.Utils.YafUserProfile">
<providers>
<clear/>
<add connectionStringName="ConfettiSQL" name="YafProfileProvider" type="YAF.Providers.Profile.YafProfileProvider"/>
</providers>
</profile>

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a Web Site Project or a Web Application Project? If you are using the ASP.NET Web site project template, you have Profiles out of the box. If you are using an ASP.NET Web Application project template, you can use the Web Profile Builder to set up Profiles:

http://weblogs.asp.net/joewrobel/archive/2008/02/03/web-profile-builder-for-web-application-projects.aspx

Comment: Hi, it's a web site project, that's what I don't understand. Is there any way to register the dll?

Comment: Registering the DLL is not the problem. In a web application project, there is no ProfileCommon class; you need to generate strongly-typed proxy class to access the profile. If you're using VS2005 go with the first link, otherwise try the second link :-)

Comment: Hi IrishCheiftain, it's not a web application project, it's a web site project? -thanks for the reply -melt

Comment: Have you configured it to run under 2.0?

Comment: Hi, Under View > Property Pages > Build...my target framework is set to 3.5. My web host also has up to 3.5 installed. The funny thing is, I have the appliacation running fine on my dev PC, just can't get it to work on my web host.

Comment: Try it under 2.0 and see? Is YAF 2.0? I'm not familiar with it but you should double check that. Also double check the syntax in your Web.Config for profiles - get another sample somewhere and do a side-by-side.

Comment: Hi, the latest version of YAF uses 3.5 SP1, thats waht I have on my dev machine and it works fine. My web host also has 3.5 SP1, but I always get the following error: "The type or namespace name 'ProfileCommon' could not be found".

Comment: The web config works fine on my dev machine. My web host only offer the option to target either framework 1.1 or 2.0/3.0/3.5 SP1 combined. I don't understand this problem at all.

Comment: Is YAF running as a standalone project? Did you confirm that you're running it as 2.0?

Comment: The leedumond.com entry is gone

Comment: Thanks, I'll remove it.