# The type or namespace name 'ProfileCommon' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Gooday, I'm creating an ASP.NET with C# Website in Visual Studio. I used ProfileCommon and stumbled upon this error:

> The type or namespace name 'ProfileCommon' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Hope it has a quick fix? **What directive should I include?** Thanks a lot.

EDIT: Any advice? - After I installed this add-in:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WebProfileBuilder/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=980

> `Error    1   The "BuildWebProfile" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance
>   of a String. Parameter name: s    at
>   System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)    at
>   WebProfileBuilder.Builder.IsProfileSame()    at
>   WebProfileBuilder.Builder.GenerateWebProfile(BuildWebProfile
>   buildWebProfile)    at WebProfileBuilder.BuildWebProfile.Execute()
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(EngineProxy
>   engineProxy, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask,
>   ITask task, Boolean& taskResult)  Cinemax`

Comment: Website or Web Application Project template?

Comment: ASP.NET web application, Irish.

Comment: Then follow links in my answer :)

Comment: Thank you, Irish! Your option is the third I try. Third time lucky, I hope! Will tell you how it goes.

Comment: Irish, what should I use instead of "namespace LD.Sample.BLL"? Or should I copy that line as such? What does it mean? I'm reading this: leedumond.com/blog/asp-net-profiles-in-web-application-projects. I downloaded the archive and noticed your project/solution's called "LD.SAMPLE". SO should I write [my project name].BLL?

Comment: Also, where should I put this class? I normally put all my classes inside App_Code, would that be fine?

Comment: Yes, try putting it the App_Code folder :)

Comment: LD.Sample.WAP and LD.Sample.BLL are the two folders with classes, from one of your links: leedumond.com/blog/asp-net-profiles-in-web-application-projects. Namespaces such as LD.Sample.BLL are contained within some class files. I don't know what to do with them.

Comment: Change the namespaces to match your own project.

Comment: Well, I tried it and it didn't work.  `<profile defaultProvider="LD.SampleWAP.ProfileProvider" inherits="LD.Sample.BLL.CustomProfile">
      <providers>
        <add name="LD.SampleWAP.ProfileProvider"
        type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"
        applicationName="/"
        connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"/>
      </providers>` As you see there are two namespaces there: LD.SampleWAP and LD.Sample.BLL. I only have one called Cinemax. Not two. The explanations are very scarce on that page and I probably didn't adapt it well to my project.

Comment: I basically created 3 classes as your link suggests: Personal, Preferences , CustomProfile, then added the above small snippet of code in web.config. But I probably didn't adapt them well. For example, for the class that starts like this: `namespace LD.Sample.BLL { using System.Web; using System.Web.Profile;   public class CustomProfile : ProfileBase { ....` I put namespace Cinemax in the beginning instead of namespace LD.Sample.BLL. I don't quite see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: There are a couple of gotchas, see my own blog post on getting this to work: http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/07/10/ASPNET-PayPal-Subscriptions-IPN.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Look here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1031740.aspx/1 or here [Error "The type or namespace name 'ProfileCommon' could not be found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743664/error-the-type-or-namespace-name-profilecommon-could-not-be-found)

The base class for the profiles is ProfileBase class which is used to handle the user profiles.
When the web application has the user profile as enabled, a new class gets created called ProfileCommon. This class is used for the accessors for each property which is defined in the profile configuration section. The accessors of ProfileCommon class then calls the getter and setter to retrieve and set the property values.

You need to add `using System.Configuration;` and `System.Web.Profile;` to your project.

You might get further information here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilebase.aspx

Hope that helps !

Comment: ThankS Jason. I tried the first link and installed the add-in but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Try the last link with the explications coming from the MSDN, that should help you.

Comment: are you you using System.Web.Profile; ?

Comment: Yes, I just added the System.Web.Profile, but still the same error.

Comment: visit this link you might find an answer http://weblogs.asp.net/joewrobel/archive/2008/02/03/web-profile-builder-for-web-application-projects.aspx

Comment: Thank you MMK, I tried that but I get the error I mention in the question update. It's a pity because I really liked the documentation. Did it work for you for Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 1):

Very likely you're using the Web Application project template. Profiles only come out of the box with the website project template. For a solution, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490754/profilecommon-could-be-not-found) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572437/the-name-profilecommon-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context).

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to add the profile Element to the web.config file.

```
<profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyCustomProfileProvider">
...
</profile>
```

see [MSDN -profile Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164644(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time to understand the issue. For me, WebApplication project works fine localy but I got this error on deployed version of WebApplication. WebApplication does not create ProfileCommon class automatically. Therefore, I create following class in project (without namespace that all generated code will see it):

```
public class ProfileCommon: ProfileBase
{
}
```

That`s it!

But if you use Profile property of page for getting and updating current user profile, you can inherit from your profile class instead of ProfileBase

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with ProfileCommon not being found and my ASP.NET Web Site not building with the very unhelpful error:

```
The type initializer for 'System.Web.Compilation.CompilationLock' threw an exception.
```

I was able to fix it by correcting the capitalization of the sessionState mode in my Web.config file to:

```xml
<sessionState mode="Off"/>
```